# Azue NuGet cannot install StackExchange.Redis 1.0.316.0

Tags: .net, azure, msbuild, nuget-package

I set up Azure deployment from Github. When do the deployment, it encountered the following error:

> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.0.316.0, Culture=neutral,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

I can not do anything on the disk because it is on Azure. How can I fix Azure so that it can download the package StackExchange.Redis, Version=1.0.316.0?

Comment: Um... there is no 1.0.316.0, AFAIK (and: I'm the package owner). Have you tried re-adding the reference from NuGet? Also, the current version is 1.0.488

Comment: I have already config 1.0.488 in packages.config, see <package id="StackExchange.Redis" version="1.0.488" targetFramework="net45" /> not sure why  when Azure do deployment, NuGet try to download the version 1.0.316.0 but not 1.0.488?

Comment: I would search for the string 1.0.316 in your files... that is - just odd

Comment: @MarcGravell File version of StackExchange.Redis.dll is 1.0.488 but assembly version is 1.0.316.0, that might cause problems.